# Number format in IE11 and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I am trying this code:

`Intl.NumberFormat('ar').format(99)`

In IE11 I am getting number converted to Arabic numerals but not in chrome.

PS: I am just passing language code, not region locale.

Comment: [Issue 1194438](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1194438&q=numberformat&can=2): _"This is a deliberate change we decide to make numbering systems for Arabic language stick with Latn numeric and differ from CLDR."_

Comment: Use the options to overwrite the scheme: `Intl.NumberFormat('ar', { numberingSystem: 'arab' }).format(99)`

Comment: seems IE11 was right all along... :P

Comment: i guess `numberingSystem`  is not available for IE11

Comment: No. But IE is dead...

Answer (score 1):

Possible fixes with the numbering system:

```js
console.log("Default             : ",Intl.NumberFormat('ar').format(99));

console.log("With u-nu-arab      : ",Intl.NumberFormat('ar-u-nu-arab').format(99));

console.log("With NumberingSystem: ",Intl.NumberFormat('ar',{numberingSystem:"arab"}).format(99));
```